# How to cluster label (in a multilabel classification problem) which mostly appear together in a class

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, cluster-analysis, multilabel-classification

to cluster label (in a multilabel classification problem) which mostly appear together in a dataframe? For example i have this dataframe:

```
text     |   genre
===========================
text 1   | [action,mistery,horror,thriller]
text 2   | [drama,romance]
text 3   | [comedy,drama,romance]
text 4   | [scifi,mystery,horror,thriller]
text 5   | [horror,mystery,thriller]
```

How can i cluster the tag that often appear together?for example, genre "mystery","horror","thriller" often appear together (3 times), genre "drama","romance" often appears together (2 times).

Comment: What is the expected output? Can it be a separate list?

Comment: for example like a cluster, with each cluster contains genres that often appear together

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to perform frequent pattern mining, also known as association rule mining. Sometimes people refer to is as association rule learning, here's a Wikipedia link to the concept: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning.

The algorithms in the frequent pattern mining domain will generally rank label combinations according to the frequency of their appearance in the data. You can specify the minimum and a maximum number of labels in a pattern and select the support and confidence thresholds. Without these constraints, the output will include all possible combinations of the labels and their counts, support, and confidence values.